# Maxlength of a text field is not being readout by Jaws

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

Maxlength of a text field is not being readout by Jaws. Is there a way by which this information can be made availble to the screen reader users?

Answer (score 5):

As a screen reader user who has used Jaws for the passed 12 years the answer is no. If something has a limited length such as a username or password you should note this on the text of the page near the form field with the limited length. For example near a username field you could put something like "Username must be between 8 and 20 characters, contain letters or numbers, and cannot contain spaces or punctuation"

Comment: +1 That information should be surfaced to _all_ users in a manner that's more obvious than the "I can't type anymore" behavior that maxlength triggers in browsers.